# Where to position dracaena in room?

Tags: sunlight, dracaena

I have a dracaena marginata plant in a pot in my room upstairs.  This room has a westward facing window which provides direct sunlight for some portion of the day.

Would it be better to put my plant in or close to the direct sunlight? or would this plant grow better in the corner of the room with much more limited sunlight?

Answer (score 2):

[Dracaena marginata](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b592) grows best in bright indirect light.  If you put it in the corner of the room chances are good it will only be getting enough light to get by.

It will survive but people tend to water too much in lower light which can cause root rot.

You could always rotate the plant between the two positions every month.